# Unexpected output for global array of structs in C

Tags: c, struct, malloc, global-variables, header-files

I am trying to manipulate a dynamically allocated array of structs, but I cannot get the data to save across function calls despite the fact it is a global variable. I am using a header file to declare the global variable, a file with the same name as the header file with the function implementations, and the main file that runs the program. Here are the contents of the three files:

things.h:

```
struct st {
    int number;
};

struct st *test;

// Function Declarations
int A();
int B();
```

things.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <things.h>

    int A() {

        // Allocate size for 10 struct st's
    test = malloc(10*sizeof(test));
    test[5].number = -1;
    printf("%d\n", test[5].number);

    B();

    return 0;
}


int B() {

    printf("%d\n", test[5].number);

    return 0;
}
```

mainFile.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <things.h>

int main() {

    A();

    return 0;
}
```

Not sure what the problem is. The expected output is:

```
-1
-1
```

but the output I get is:

```
`-1`
`some-random-number-here`
```

This is a very simple copy of what I am actually working on, so don't worry about the dynamic allocation (has to be dynamic) and checking if it returns NULL first.

Edit:

As @xing and @cdarke mentioned, my problem was with my malloc. Working as expected now.

Comment: `test` is a pointer, so `10*sizeof(test)` is the size of 10 pointers, not 10 structs.  Use `sizeof(*test)`

Comment: That was indeed the problem, working as expected now.

Comment: I can not see error here. At least my platform has `sizeof(*) > sizeof(int)`. Maybe you need to add `fflush` at the end of main?